# point to virtual directory in IIS

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

I apologize if I am not using the right technical terminology, but I am trying to be as clear as possible, I hope my post makes sense.

I have added a local classic ASP website in IIS 7.5

Sites
    csr < website

The physical files location: c:\projects\webapps\csr

The URL in the browser: http://localhost:82/orders.asp?.....

My question is: how do I have to change the configuration if I want the website to open in the browser using the following URL: http://localhost:82/**csr**/orders.asp?....

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the website's path to `c:\projects\webapps`. Then http://localhost:82 will point to `c:\projects\webapps` and http://localhost:82/csr will point to `c:\projects\webapps\csr`

If you want http://localhost:82 to point to some other folder, that's fine too. Just add a virtual directory to the website, name it "csr" and give it the path `c:\projects\webapps\csr`, and you'll be able to browse to http://localhost:82/csr.